# mongo db text search error no text index for

Tags: mongodb, search, text, mongoose

I'm trying to use mongo db text search but I get the following msg error - no text index for
Although you can see that there are text indexes in db.items. what's the problem? what is the command in mongoose?

```
> db.items.getIndexes()
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "db.items",
        "name" : "_id_"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "color" : "text",
            "category_A" : "text",
            "category_B" : "text",
            "category_C" : "text"
        },
        "ns" : "db.items",
        "name" : "type_text_color_text_category_A_text_category_B_text_category_C_text",
        "sparse" : false,
        "background" : false
    }
]
> db.items.runCommand( "text",{search:"D"})
{ "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "no text index for: db.items" }
```

Answer (score 2):

First, did you start mongo with `textSearchEnabled=true` (see [Enable text search](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-text-search/))?

If you're using a config file (e.g. `/etc/mongodb.conf`) the correct line should be:

`setParameter = textSearchEnabled=true`

Second, your index looks like a regular index rather than text. Please post the command you used.

---

If you want to test the text index function, try the following:

Drop your current index (it may interfere with the new one you'll create)

`db.items.dropIndex("type_text_color_text_category_A_text_category_B_text_category_C_text")`

and create a new one

`db.items.ensureIndex( {type:"text"}, {unique: false, name: "type_index"})`

and then try the search again.

You may also need to run `db.items.reIndex()`.